# Enum Converting Name Response

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hello I have Enum below;

```
   public enum TaskStatusEnum {
      
      READY(1, "Ready");
      ON_GOING(2, "On going");
    
    private final long id;
    private final long description;
 

     public static TaskStatusEnum get(long id) {
    
     for (TaskStatusEnum status : TaskStatusEnum.values()) {
         
       if(status.id== id) {
    
        return status;
      
       }
     }
    
      return null;
     }
    }
```

But on the Response I see my Response

taskStatus : ON_GOING
taskStatus : READY

how to prevent this Thank you

Comment: What you want to prevent ? showing in response ? or you want to show in different way

Comment: I like to show as ready, on going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonValue` annotation on the field you want to serialize/deserialize upon.
Following is the complete code example

```
enum TaskStatusEnum{

READY(1, "Ready"),
ON_GOING (2,"On going");

private final long id;

@JsonValue
private final String description;

TaskStatusEnum (int id, String ready)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.description = ready;
}

public static TaskStatusEnum get (long id)
{
    for (TaskStatusEnum status : TaskStatusEnum.values()) {
        if (status.id == id) {
            return status;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonValue` on getter of `description` in enum to deserialize `description` value

```
@JsonValue
public double getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

And if you want to serialize and deserialize both then use it on field.